# multithread: java condition await timeout but can't return

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

```
Lock sharedLock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
```

main thread:

```
sharedLock.lock();
childThread.start();
condition.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
sharedLock.unlock();
```

child thread:

```
sharedLock.lock();
//do something, may take a long time
Thread.sleep(10);// sleep to simulate a long execution
condition.signal();
sharedLock.unlock();
```

Suppose child thread send a network request and wait for response, I want main thread wait at most 5 seconds, if timeout, retry the request. but when the `await()` timeout, it cannot acquire lock because child thread still hold it, so it still wait the lock until child thread release it, which takes 10 seconds.

How can I achieve my requirement that main thread wait child thread's signal, but have a bounded timeout?

Comment: Are you required to use `Lock` and `Condition` (like in an assignment)? There are simpler solutions than building such a try-at-most mechanic out of locks and conditions.

Comment: what is the purpose of your sharedLock? what do you want to prevent with it?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I want to use signal and await. the condition.await and condition.signal must be used with lock, or the await and signal method cannot be called.

Comment: @zapl I need a timeout-and-retry mechanic, do you have any other solution except using a spin lock(like while(!isFinished && waitedTime < 10))

Comment: this is not my question I know what is a Lock, what I don't get/know is what you want to do with it

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I want to use await and signal to implement a timeout-and-retry mechanic, if the child thread exceed the time bound, the main thread will do a retry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how your are supposed to do it, you are supposed to:

1. Create an `ExecutorService` (thread pool) for that you should check the methods of the class `Executors` to choose the best one in your case but `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` is a good start
2. Submit your task as a `FutureTask` to the thread pool
3. Then call `get` with a timeout
4. Manage properly the `TimeoutException`

Here is how it could be done:

```
// Total tries
int tries = 3;
// Current total of tries
int tryCount = 1;
do {
    // My fake task to execute asynchronously
    FutureTask<Void> task = new FutureTask<>(
        () -> {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return null;
        }
    );
    // Submit the task to the thread pool
    executor.submit(task);
    try {
        // Wait for a result during at most 1 second
        task.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // I could get the result so I break the loop
        break;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // The timeout has been reached
        if (tryCount++ == tries) {
            // Already tried the max allowed so we throw an exception
            throw new RuntimeException(
                String.format("Could execute the task after %d tries", tries),
                e
            );
        }
    }
} while (true);
```

> How can I achieve my requirement that main thread wait child thread's
>   signal, but have a bounded timeout?

Here is how you can achieve your requirements:

Main Thread:

```
lock.lock();
try {
    childThread.start();
    condition.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} finally {
    sharedLock.lock();
}
```

The child thread:

```
try {
    //do something, may take a long time
    Thread.sleep(10);// sleep to simulate a long execution
} finally {
    // Here we notify the main thread that the task is complete whatever
    // the task failed or not
    lock.lock();
    try {
        condition.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

As you can see to work, the task must not be performed within the critical section, we only acquire the lock to notify the main thread nothing more. Otherwise if you execute the task within the critical section after the timeout the main thread will still need to acquire the lock once again and since the lock is actually owned by the child thread, it will need to wait anyway until the end of the task which makes the timeout totally useless.

**NB:** I renamed `sharedLock` to `lock` as a `ReentrantLock` is an exclusive lock not as shared lock, if you need a shared lock check the class `Semaphore` to define the total amount of permits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it make sense. But I still wonder in which case the condition.await(timeout, TimeUnit) will make sense. The await method need to require the lock before return. In normal case, it receives a signal from the other thread which release the lock, so the await can return. But in the case timeout, the other thread still hold the lock. So the timeout arguments in await() method won't take effect.

Comment: I saw my answer was once the accepted answer. I'm glad this answer is more helpful than mine. Buf if my answer is a bit helpful to you, would you mind upvote that and this? I put a lot of work in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified with [intrinsic lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

```
Object sharedObj = new Object();
```

main thread:

```
    synchronized (sharedObj) {
      int retryCount = 0;
      while (retryCount < maxRetry) {
        sharedObj.wait(5000);
        retryCount++;
      }
    }
```

child thread:

```
    synchronized (sharedObj) {
      //do something, may take a long time
      Thread.sleep(10);// sleep to simulate a long execution
      sharedObj.notify();
    }
```

---

> java condition await timeout but can't return

That's because the lock must be released so *wait/await* can return. So your child thread should be like:

```
    //do something, may take a long time
    Thread.sleep(10);// sleep to simulate a long execution
    synchronized (sharedObj) {
      sharedObj.notify();
    }
```

Java's *wait/notify* is usually used to solve producer-consumer problem. **And usually *sharedObj* shouldn't be holded for too long. Then your main thread can hold the lock again when the *wait* timeout.**

Take a look at an in-production example: [hadoop/hdfs/DFSOutputStream.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.6.4/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSOutputStream.java)
The logic is simple, the producer creates packet and put it in dataQueue

```
// takes a long time to create packet
synchronized (dataQueue) {
  dataQueue.addLast(packet);
  dataQueue.notifyAll();
}
```

The consumer wait while dataQueue is empty:

```
    synchronized (dataQueue) {
      while ((!shouldStop() && dataQueue.size() == 0 &&... ) {
        try {
          dataQueue.wait(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException  e) {
          LOG.warn("Caught exception", e);
        }
        doSleep = false;
        now = Time.monotonicNow();
      }
```

As you can see, the *dataQueue* are unlocked for most of the time!

> How can I achieve my requirement that main thread wait child thread's signal, but have a bounded timeout?

If your child thread are mostly in a loop, your Main thread can set a *isRunning* flag to make child thread stop by itself. If your child thread are mostly blocking by an I/O operation, your Main thread can interrupt the child thread.

The sharedObj is used for coordination and protects *sharedObj*. If there's other resources should be protected, you have 2 choices:
1. If the operation on the resource is quick, like *ackQueue* in *DFSOutputStream.java*, protect it together inside the *sharedObj*.
2. If the operation on the resource is time-consuming, do it and protect it outside the *sharedObj*.

Answer (score 0):

The valid confusion in the question is because the "Thread.sleep(10)" is done inside the lock block. When await(long time, TimeUnit unit) has to return because of timeout, it still needs the lock. So, as suggested in the other answer the long running task should not be inside the lock for it to work properly.
But it would be nice to have proper documentation stressing this fact. For example, if we await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) i.e wait for 5 seconds and the lock is available 10 seconds after the call,  it will still return false even though the lock is available now at the moment of return.